# django.db.utils.IntegrityError, invalid foreign key. Can someone help me and teach me what happens?

Tags: django, database, sqlite

can someone help me and teach me what happens?
For me not to make mistakes again?

I want to bind a foreign key (class category) to my course class. And I did something that doesn't allow me to get out of it.

```
  Error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'courses_course'
with primary key '3' has an invalid foreign key: 
courses_course.category_id contains a value 'outros' that does not have a 
corresponding value in courses_category.id.
```

```
 CATEGORY = [('eng','ENGENHARIA'),('prog','PROGRAMAÇÃO'),('hum','HUMANAS'),('saude','SAÚDE'), 
('outros','OUTROS')]    // i'm from brazil 

class Category(models.Model):
    title_category = models.CharField('Nome da Categoria', max_length= 63 , choices = CATEGORY )

class Course(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField('Nome', max_length= 100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Atalho',max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField('Descricao',blank = True)
    follows = models.IntegerField(default = 0)  //allows negative numbers, I know. I'll fix it ...
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'courses/images',verbose_name= 'Imagem', 
    null=True, blank = True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Criado em',auto_now_add = True )
    updated_at= models.DateTimeField( 'Atualizado em', auto_now = True )
```

Does anyone imagine another structure or class that allows you to create educational courses / videos that have categories? Or am I on the right track for a beginner?

Comment: When you get this error? in views? Please share the script

Comment: Have you recently changed the definition of the `category` foreign key? The only thing I can think of is that it previously was referencing the `title_category` field from the `Category` model. Was `title_category` previously the pk on the `Category` model or was `to_field=''title_category` passed to the `category` foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can guess with the information you gave (you didn't say WHEN you get this error) is that you tried to do something such as :

```
my_course.category = 'outros'
my_course.save()
```

Which is incorrect since it isn't a Category object. A `ForeignKey` field must refer to an object of type to which you point to.

```
category = Category.objects.create(title_category='outros')
my_course.category = category
my_course.save()
```

This would work since you give a reference to a Category object in your Course object.

Do not hesitate to read the documentation about [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) fields again.

Comment: Oh you get this error while trying to migrate.. Note that before trying to do `python manage.py migrate` you should do a `python manage.py makemigrations`. Did you do that ?